# Create blank in row element if condition is met

Tags: r

I have data frame as follows:

```
              df <- data.frame(Resource_Code = c("B-T234","B-T234","B-T234"),
             "Valid_To"= c("2021-10-17", "2021-11-28", "2021-10-31"),
             "V1"= c("2021-10-17", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-24"),
             "V2" = c("2021-10-24", "2021-10-31", "2021-10-31"),
             "V3" = c("2021-10-31", "2021-11-07", "2021-11-14"),
             "V4" = c("2021-11-14", "2021-11-21", "2021-11-28"),
             "V5" = c("2021-12-05", "2021-11-28", "2021-12-12"),
             "V6" = c("2021-12-12", "2021-12-19", "2021-12-26"),
             "V7" = c("2022-01-02", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-16"),
             "V8" = c("2022-01-23", "2022-01-30", "2022-02-06"),
             "V9" = c("2022-02-13", "2022-02-20", "2022-02-27"),
             "v10" = c("2022-02-27", "2022-03-06", "2022-03-13"))
```

In the desired output, if any row cell(column V1 onwards) is equal to corresponding "Valid_To" row cell  then subsequent cell (column V1 onwards) should become blank

Actual DF has hundreads of rows and columns and column V1 to VN in date format

The desired output is as follows:

```
              df1 <- data.frame(Resource_Code = c("B-T234","B-T234","B- 
              T234"),
             "Valid_To"= c("2021-10-17", "2021-11-28", "2021-10-31"),
             "V1"= c("2021-10-17", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-24"),
             "V2" = c("", "2021-10-31", "2021-10-31"),
             "V3" = c("", "2021-11-07", ""),
             "V4" = c("", "2021-11-21", ""),
             "V5" = c("", "2021-11-28", ""),
             "V6" = c("", "", ""),
             "V7" = c("", "", ""),
             "V8" = c("", "", ""),
             "V9" = c("", "", ""),
             "v10" = c("", "", ""))
```

My code is as follows:
My code is NOT giving desired output
Please help

```
             for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
                 for (j in 3:ncol(df1) ){
                     if (df[i,j] == df1[1,2]){
                         df[i,j + 1] <- "" 
                                             }

                                        }
                                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base vectorised solution

```
tmp=grepl("V[0-9]+",colnames(df))
df[,tmp][df[,"Valid_To",drop=T]<df[,tmp]]=NA

  Resource_Code   Valid_To         V1         V2         V3         V4         V5   V6   V7
1        B-T234 2021-10-17 2021-10-17       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA>
2        B-T234 2021-11-28 2021-10-17 2021-10-31 2021-11-07 2021-11-21 2021-11-28 <NA> <NA>
3        B-T234 2021-10-31 2021-10-24 2021-10-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA>
    V8   V9        v10
1 <NA> <NA> 2022-02-27
2 <NA> <NA> 2022-03-06
3 <NA> <NA> 2022-03-13
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R way using `apply`.

`match` returns the position where the `Valid_To` value matches the date in columns `V1` to `V10`. If the `match` exist then we turn the values to blank from the next position till end of the series.

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
  inds <- match(x[1], x[-1])
  if(length(inds)) x[(inds + 2):length(x)] <- ''
  x
}))
df

#  Resource_Code   Valid_To         V1         V2         V3         V4         V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 v10
#1        B-T234 2021-10-17 2021-10-17                                                            
#2        B-T234 2021-11-28 2021-10-17 2021-10-31 2021-11-07 2021-11-21 2021-11-28                
#3        B-T234 2021-10-31 2021-10-24 2021-10-31
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use loop,

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  dummy <- c()
  for (j in 3:dim(df)[2]){
    if (df[i,j] == df[i,2]){
      dummy <- c(dummy, j)
    }
  }
  check <- min(dummy) + 1
  df[i,c(check: dim(df)[2])] <- NA
}
df

  Resource_Code   Valid_To         V1         V2         V3         V4         V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  v10
1        B-T234 2021-10-17 2021-10-17       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2        B-T234 2021-11-28 2021-10-17 2021-10-31 2021-11-07 2021-11-21 2021-11-28 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3        B-T234 2021-10-31 2021-10-24 2021-10-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```